# Does Ireland have any other MEPs than Claire Daley and Mick Wallace, and why does it have such antiwar MEPs compared to seemingly

Tags: european-parliament, ireland

[Claire Daley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clare_Daly) and [Mick Wallace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mick_Wallace) are both extremely anti NATO and anti war. And they are both from Ireland. Is such sentiment really simply so strong throughout the electorate of the ROI? Is there some other explanation? Do they constitute 100% of the Irish MEPs? Do all countries have an equal number of representatives? Otherwise how are they allocated?

Comment: Why don't you just Google such basic facts as Ireland MEP? The first link goes to the Wikipedia page. And I have copied the link, but it is so basic that I refuse to even pasting it.

Comment: You need to pick one question and focus on it.

Answer (score 2):

First question:
Ireland is not the only country with anti-war MEPs. Clare Daly and Mick Wallace are members of the GUE/NGL, which has 37 MEPs from about a dozen countries. A number of member parties of the GUE/NGL are critical of NATO and the Western defense assistance to Ukraine.

However, the election did take place before the Russian escalation of the 'frozen' conflict in 2022, so that cannot be used to gauge the mood of the electorate.

Second question:
The number of Irish MEP is extremely easy to [google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment_in_the_European_Parliament). The number of seats is set by treaty, and smaller countries are somewhat over-represented on a per-capita basis.

Answer (score 1):

Ireland [has](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/ireland/en/your-meps) 13 MEPs. I don't know a lot about their positions on broader topics like NATO etc., but on a quick search, the two you've mentioned stand apart on some *Ukraine* war issues, as Irish Times [reported](https://www.irishtimes.com/politics/2023/01/19/meps-wallace-and-daly-vote-against-call-for-tribunal-to-prosecute-russia-for-invasion-of-ukraine/) on Jan 19:

> Clare Daly and Mick Wallace were among 19 members of the European Parliament to vote against a resolution calling for the establishment of a special international tribunal to prosecute Russia’s leadership for the crime of aggression against Ukraine.
>
> The resolution was passed with 472 votes in favour and 33 abstentions in a European Parliament plenary session in Strasbourg on Thursday. Two of Mr Wallace and Ms Daly’s fellow Left group MEPs, Sinn Féin’s Chris MacManus and Independent Luke ‘Ming’ Flanagan, were not present for the vote. All other Irish MEPs voted in favour.

And [according](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mick_Wallace#Member_of_the_European_Parliament) to Wikipedia, Daly and Wallace often travel together and embraced other "leftist" (or better said anti-Western) causes like Assad in Syria, Maduro in Venezuela, attacked the Belarus opposition (essentially embracing Lukashenko) etc. The two [were](https://www.world-today-news.com/see-the-only-meps-who-voted-against-condemning-the-russian-invasion-of-ukraine-russia/) among the 13 MEPs that voted against condemning Russia's invasion of Ukraine. (If you're curious, Greece "bested" Ireland on that with 3 MEPs opposing--two far-left and one far-right. But Greece [has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_members_of_the_European_Parliament_for_Greece,_2019%E2%80%932024) 21 MEPs in total.)

Furthermore, the 4 Irish MEPs in the Left (EU) group actually come from different Irish parties. Daly and Wallace are both from [Independents 4 Change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independents_4_Change) (I4C), which is more like a [protest party](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42170/why-are-british-voters-more-likely-to-back-the-main-parties-in-general-elections) that has very little national representation, but (like many other protest parties) does better in secondary elections like the EU ones. I4C attracted 0.4% of the (first pref.) vote in the 2020 national elections (and has one [TD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Irish_general_election#Results) out of 160), but 7.4% of the (first pref.) vote in the 2019 EU elections. I4C did a little better in the 2016 national elections, when they got 1.5% of the (first pref.) vote, and so had 4 TDs back then. (Somewhat hilariously, Sinn Féin has only one MEP, but the 2nd greatest number of TDs in the last election, 37, and they had the highest share of the [first pref.] votes in that election, 24.5%. Sinn Féin performed [more] poorly in the 2019 EU election though, with only 11.7% of the [first pref.] vote.)

I don't know where Flanagan stands on Ukraine or NATO, but according to his Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_%27Ming%27_Flanagan#European_Parliament) he was elected on an anti-EU platform, so it seems he's also a "protest vote", basically. Among the few positions that Wikipedia details about him, is that he wants Ireland to leave the eurozone.

Comment: What is a “secondary” election?